# Differences between svn merge left, right & working files after conflicts

Tags: svn

When performing a 'svn merge' from my development team's trunk into a branch, we occasionally experience merge conflicts that produce files with suffix names: `*.merge-right.r5004`, `*.merge-left.r4521` and `*.working`.  I've searched throughout Subversions's documentation but their explanation hasn't been much use.  I've gathered the following:

- *.merge-right.r5004 = trunk version
- *.merge-left.r4521  = ?
- *.working           = branch version

I can't seem to figure out what `merge-left.r4521` is.  And if the answer is that its simply an older version of the file from branch, then why 4521?

Comment: Just a thought - is it the revision of the trunk when the branch was created?

Comment: Number after `r` is revision number. File with extension .rXXX is that file in that given revision.

Comment: There's a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673658/svnmerge-workflow

Answer (score 81):

Let's say there are two branches, and last (`HEAD`) revision in branch `A` is `9`, while it is `6` in branch `B`.

When `cd B; svn merge -r 5:8 ^/braches/A` is ran, svn will try to apply delta between `5` and `8` from branch `A` on top of branch `B`.

(In other words, change sets `7` and `8` will be applied to `B`)

```
common
ancestor      left     right
(1)━━┱───(3)──(5)──(7)──(8)──(9)  # branch A
     ┃         └┄┄┄┄┬┄┄┄┄┘
     ┃              ↓
     ┗━(2)━━(4)━━(6)              # branch B
               working
```

If the delta applies cleanly, it's all good.

Let's say some lines were modified in change set `3`, and same source lines were modified differently in change set `4`.

If delta (`5`→`8`) doesn't touch those lines, all is still good.

If delta (`5`→`8`) also modified what `3` and `4` did, changes cannot be merged automatically, and svn leaves a file in conflict state:

- `file` --- file with (`working`, `left`, `right`) delimited
- `file.working` --- state of file in branch `B@6`
- `file.merge-left` --- state of file in branch `A@5`
- `file.merge-right` --- state of file in branch `A@8`

If you edit such a file manually, you have a few choices --- keep `working` (your version), keep `right` (their version; the other branch version) or merge the changes manually.

`Left` is not useful in itself, there's no point to keep `left` (their old version) in the file.

It is, however, useful for tools. `left`→`right` is the change set.

When you see, for example:

```py
<<<<<<< .working

    life_universe_and_everything = 13

||||||| .merge-left.r5

    life_universe_and_everything = "13"

=======

    life_universe_and_everything = "42"

>>>>>>> .merge-right.r8
```

In branch `A`, `"13"` (str) was changed to `"42"`.

Branch `B` had `13` (int).

Perhaps you want `42` (int) when you reconcile this conflict manually.

Comment: finally, an explanation that I can understand. thank you!

Answer (score 14):

file.merge-left.r4521 is the latest change of this file in the left branch (i.e. the origin) **before** the right branch (the destination) were created.

In other words, merge-left.r4521 it's the first version of the file to be merged

with merge-right.r5004 (the latest version of the destination branch)

**For example**, say you want to merge branches Left and Right as below:

```
Left   1   2   f.3   4   f.5   6    7    f.9    11 

Right                                  8    f.10    f.12   13


Right is created in 8 ( is a copy of 7 )

file 'f' has been modified in 3, 5, 9, 10, 12

The merge of file 'f' will occur between 7 and 13 because

7 is the latest version of file f in Left before Right was created

13 is the latest version of Right
```

Answer (score 11):

- 'file.py.merge-left.rxxx` shows the merging result taking the left side of the conflict
- 'file.py.merge-right.ryyy` shows the merging result taking the right side of the conflict
- 'file.py.working` shows your unchanged working copy
- 'file.py` shows SVNs attempts to merge both

This question is similar to [stackoverflow.com/questions/1673658/svnmerge-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673658/svnmerge-workflow) but this one is more specific about the content of the conflict files.

Comment: Your answer suggests .merge-right and .working should agree for the most of the cases (when we start from an unchanged checkout of the "right") but that does not agree with my observation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "left" file is the last version where the file was the same in the trunk and the branch (for your question, but it would be between the source and dest in general).

If you've never merged changes from the trunk into your branch then this would be the version of the trunk when a branch (copy) was performed.  Otherwise, it's the last version of the trunk that was merged and committed to this branch.

The left and right are what is used to create the diff that will be applied (as a patch) to the working file.

Answer (score -2):

You performed 3-side merge diring conflict-resolving (when merging **2 different files**). It this operation 3 sources used

- "your" file (from WC or source-location, depending on parameters)
- "their" file (file with with changes  must be merged)
- "base" file (common ancestor of files 1-2)

r*** extension just added to the same filename in order to have 3 files on merge

After successful  merging and marking conflict as resolved temp-files must disappear automagically, if my memory served me well