# svn merge left, right & working ms word (doc) files after conflicts

Tags: svn, merge, ms-word, tortoisesvn

I have a ms word file named filename.doc. After merge it from trunk to my working branch (sync) tortoiseSVN created 3 new files for conflict resolution:

- filename.doc.merge-left.r29985
- filename.doc.merge-right.r29986
- filename.doc.working

At this time, filename.doc become an encrypted file, invalid for opening with MS Word.

Trying to resolve the conflict with MS Word 2007 does not work, it tries to compare with de encrypted file. With MS Word 2010 it's compared with working file extension ending the conflict.

I read [Differences between svn merge left, right & working files after conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679113/differences-between-svn-merge-left-right-working-files-after-conflicts) and [svnmerge workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673658/svnmerge-workflow) to understand what is this working file extension and how it works. But I'm confusing about this scenario working in newest MS Word, not on old.

On both machines the merge tool configuration is default. I have SVN Server 1.8.10, TortoiseSVN 1.8.8. Do I have to update all MS Word to 2010 (or newer)?

Comment: Just don't merge Word files with default SVN diff|merge tools. PS - filename.doc is not encrypted, just renamed

Comment: First, no suggestions? Didn't help. What diff/merge tools do you recommend in this case? Second, encrypted thus when open file I can't read it.